# Can I reference a Static Resource in an HTML Area?

Tags: apex, javascript, static-resources

I'd like to reference a Javascript file (Static Resource) in an HTML area within Salesforce - is this possible?  Or can I only reference Static Resources from a VisualForce page?

If it is possible, would I be correct in using this code to do so: `<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MyJavascriptFile}"/>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML area"? S-Controls? HTML sidebar component? I think sidebar components don't parse dollar-variables ($User, $Resource etc) nicely.

Comment: Hey eyescream, yes I'm trying to do this via sidebar component.  Would this make a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is possible.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MyJavascriptFile}"/>
```

translates to

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/resource/1233160164000/MyJavascriptFile'>
```

or more generally speaking the path will be translated to

```
/resource/<timestamp>/<name>
```

which means that you can reference your static resource without the formulas

For more details see the

Component reference: 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_includeScript.htm
and the Developer Wiki:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Delivering_Static_Resources_with_Visualforce

Comment: Thanks Seb, would this still be the case if I were referencing something in the sidebar (custom HTML component)?

Comment: absolutely. just use /resource/<timestamp>/<name> instead of the {!$Resource.} expression

Comment: Cut the timestamp part off :D Less maintenance effort when eventually you have to upload new version & timestamp changes.

Comment: ...unless you want your end-users to not use cached older versions of the resource, which is why the timestamp is there. It's a bit more maint when you change it, but you'll avoid having to tell users to ctrl-F5 to force a reload of the cached resource.

Comment: When referencing from within static resources I omit the timestamp, ex `/static-resource-name/background.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a timestamp within your static resource path seems a bit problematic if that resource is constantly updated (like a stylesheet).

Following the official [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm) and looking at the generated meta tags in a page, I found that the following path works in my community app:

`/customers/sfsites/c/resource/<static-resource-name>`